# F-string, help on formatting

Tags: python

I'm following a tutorial and trying to understand what happens here. So we are encoding 'message' to bytes first then we take the length of that and align(?) it to the left by 10 and then encode the whole thing?

I'm trying to use this part in my device that doesn't understand f-strings so I need to format it in `.format()` way instead but can't figure how to do it.

```
HEADER_LENGTH = 10
message = 'this is test message'

message = message.encode('utf-8')
message_header = f"{len(message):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: `message_header = "{:<{HL}}".format(len(message), HL=HEADER_LENGTH).encode('utf-8')`. If you're using Python 3, you don't need the `.encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: @martineau: if you don't use encode, you don't create `bytes` object, which you may need.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Strings are `utf-8` by default in Python 3 — and besides the OP said nothing about bytes.

Comment: Agreed, but if OP needs to send this message through a socket, encoding to bytes is required. This seems to be a messaging application. If bytes work, strings won't, and vice-versa.

Comment: @beniii note that if you need some serialization, I suggest you have a look at `json` to serialize your objects. Much easier than doing this by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can "downgrade" to `format` style if your target is prior to Python 3.6

```
message_header = "{ml:<{hl}}".format(ml=len(message),hl=HEADER_LENGTH).encode('utf-8')
```

`format` supports nesting so adaptation is easy. Just move evaluated variables in the `format` arguments, and use keywords, so placeholding is easier than positional (or empty-brace) style.

The above left-justifies the length of the message (as string) using `HEADER_LENGTH` length to right-pad with spaces.

Answer (score -1):

It's not an fstring after you run your code, both `message` and `message_header` are just utf-8 encoded strings.